# Jython HashMap arguments

Tags: java, python, jython, bukkit

I'm coding bukkit plugins for Minecraft servers in jython, using PyPluginLoader. I've events and everything else which works, but I want to make toggle command, which will toggle blockspawn mode on, but if you enter it again, it shuts it off. Here's the code, error below:

```
from java.io import File
import org.bukkit as bukkit
server = bukkit.Bukkit.getServer()
log = server.getLogger()
Material = bukkit.Material
from org.bukkit.event import player
from org.bukkit.entity import EntityType
import org.bukkit.permissions
from org.bukkit.plugin.java import JavaPlugin
from org.bukkit import Server
from org.bukkit import plugin
from java.util import Date, HashSet, HashMap

z = HashMap


@hook.command("blockspawn", usage="/<command>",
                desc="Toggles blockspawning mode on/off")
def onbrix(sender, command, label):
    if z.containsKey(player):
      z.remove(player.getName())
      sender.sendMessage("Blockspawning OFF")
    else:
        z.put(player.getName())
        sender.sendMessage("Blockspawning ON")
```

ERROR:

```
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<iostream>", line 23, in onbrix
TypeError: containsKey(): expected 2 args; got 1
```

Comment: Please don't add off-site links, instead post the *relevant* parts of the error message and code here.

Comment: Tracebacks are text too; copy it from the console (use the window menu to mark, then copy text) and paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should read:

```
z = HashMap()
```

Note the parentheses. Otherwise you are not creating an instance of HashMap.

Comment: Now I get this:

    Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<iostream>", line 27, in onbrix
    TypeError: put(): expected 2 args; got 1

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting it, how do I exactly make an instance of HashMap?